# How to Pass Null value while serializing Avro message

Tags: java, avro

I have field as defined as `Map<String, String> map;` , I taking request from a client and sending this to Kafka Topic having schema defined in schema registry.

In schema I have defined this as:

```
 union{null, map<string>} map;
```

But when someone is sending me a value as null I am getting this error while pushing the message to Kafka topic :

```
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: Error serializing Avro message
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null of string of map of union of event.AvroFlumeEvent
    at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumWriter.npe(GenericDatumWriter.java:184)
    at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumWriter.writeWithoutConversion(GenericDatumWriter.java:178)
    at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumWriter.write(GenericDatumWriter.java:83)
    at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumWriter.write(GenericDatumWriter.java:73)
    at io.confluent.kafka.serializers.AbstractKafkaAvroSerializer.serializeImpl(AbstractKafkaAvroSerializer.java:95)
    at io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroSerializer.serialize(KafkaAvroSerializer.java:53)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ExtendedSerializer$Wrapper.serialize(ExtendedSerializer.java:65)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ExtendedSerializer$Wrapper.serialize(ExtendedSerializer.java:55)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer.doSend(KafkaProducer.java:841)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer.send(KafkaProducer.java:803)
org.apache.flume.sink.DefaultSinkProcessor.process(DefaultSinkProcessor.java:67)
    at org.apache.flume.SinkRunner$PollingRunner.run(SinkRunner.java:145)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Input :

```
"dimensions": {
      "countryCode": "US",
      "Number": NULL

}
```

How to make take care of nulls can it be defined it in schema itself ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That schema says map **values** are not unions, so they must be non-null strings. The map itself can be null, though

I'm not if this is valid in IDL, but you can try, assuming you didn't want the map to be nullable

```
map<union{null, string}>} map;
```

Otherwise, you could define your deserializers to treat empty strings or some default value as a nullable field

Comment: what we should  be do in Avro schema side ?

Comment: What do you mean? I provided the updated schema field